# Align children to the left when parent aligns to the center

Tags: css

Is it possible to align children to the left when parent aligns to the center?

I have list of elements. Parent block should align to the center but children align to the left.

[image]

Now I can align children to the center too - [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Dgdhr/80/)

```
.parent {
  text-align: center;
}
.child {
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  margin:10px;
  display:inline-block;
  background:#e0e0e0;
}
```

Comment: I think your question and description is not clear. Question says `children to the left` and description says ` align children to the center`

Comment: Question is unclear.

Comment: Image in the question has numbers align to left in the box where your Fiddle, numbers are in the center. If you simply need to align numbers to left as in the above picture just update the child with a text-align:left..child {
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    margin:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    background:#e0e0e0;
    text-align:left;
}

Comment: I updated my question. Sorry for my English

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe, I added a image

Comment: @Fijir if you got your answer mark to accept it! Let people know what helped you..

Comment: I didn't got an answer

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
.child {
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  margin:10px;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  background:#e0e0e0;
}
```

fiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/Dgdhr/82/

Comment: Parent aligns to the left too.

Comment: @Fijir what do you mean.

Comment: I need same padding on the left and on the right. Like .parent {margin: 0 auto}. But I parent {width: 100%}

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
.parent {
text-align: center;
position:absolute;
}
.child {
width: 100px;
height:100px;
margin:10px;
display:inline-block;
background:#e0e0e0;    
position:relative;
float:left;    
}
```

Comment: Parent aligns to the left too.

Comment: Can you please try this now,


   .parent {
text-align: center;

border:solid 1px red;
 margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; width:800px; height:200px;
}
.child {
width: 100px;
height:100px;
margin:10px;
display:inline-block;
background:#e0e0e0;    
position:relative;
float:left;    
}

Answer (score 0):

Does .parent has to be `width: 100%`? If not, you can set a width and `margin: 0 auto;`. See in http://jsfiddle.net/h9xgx92u/

```
.parent {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.child {
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    margin:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    background:#e0e0e0;
}
```

Comment: .parent has to be width: 100%

Comment: I don't know if you can do it. I mean, why child items break a line if its container still have space? I would suggest you to use a intermediate parent between parent and child to accomplish this, but it depends on your scneario. I would also suggest you to use flexbox, it easier to manage things like this...

Answer (score 0):

Use **HTML** stucture like this

```
<div class='superparent'>
  <div class='parent'>
    <div class='child'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.superparent{ text-align: center;}
.parent{display:inline-block; text-align:left}
.child{display:inline-block}
```

Explanation:

1. You **need the parent to be in center** of the screen, hence **superparent has center-text-align**, along with **parent to be an inline-block**, so it doesn't occupy the default full block.
2. You **need children to be left-aligned**, so the **parent has left-text-align**, also with **children having inline-block** display attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If accept scss, you can try this:

html:

```
<div class='demo'>
    <ul class='demo__list'>
        <li class='demo__item'></li>
        <li class='demo__item'></li>
        <li class='demo__item'></li>
        <li class='demo__item'></li>
        <li class='demo__item'></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

scss:

[scss details](https://codepen.io/huangshijuan/pen/VOONQo)

But, if the total with of all child elements is less than the outer with, it's a problem.